# $\text{gcd}(d,40) = 5$, where $d$ has four digits. Determine the unknown $d$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

> $$\text{gcd}(d,40) = 5$$
>
> where $d$ has four digits. Determine the values $d$ can take.

Perhaps we can rewrite it as

$$\text{gcd}(d,40) = \text{gcd}(40,d \space (\text{mod 40}))$$

Regards

Comment: There are many $d$s with that property. Are you sure nothing's missing?

Comment: @TheSimpliFire Yes, I want to determine it all.

Comment: Sure, your rewrite is good... what does that say about the value of $(d\bmod 40)$? (it's not a single value)

Comment: @Joffan If that's not a single value, then I don't have any idea in particular.

Comment: There are four qualifying values in the range [$1..40$] that will give the final $\gcd$ of $5$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:**

We want $d$ such that $$\gcd(d,2^3\cdot5)=5.$$ This means that $d$ can have any prime  factorisation (with four digits), but must have a factor of $5$ and cannot be even...

Comment: What if $d$ has two digits?

Comment: It doesn't matter how many digits $d$ has. Apply the same principle...

Comment: @Hamilton It appears like you're asking another question. Please start another question or look at this answer and apply it to the new case. Comments are meant to clarify the questions and answers, not to start another question.

Comment: Why are you asking if $d$ has two digits?  You said you wanted one with 4 digits.  Between 1005 to 9995 you have 900 choices.  Just pick one.  If you want a two digit number just pick one from 15 to 95.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $40=5\times 2^3$ so $d$ would need to be a multiple of $5$ but not a multiple of $2$ which means any number ending in $5$.

Comment: What if $d$ has two digits?

Comment: @Hamilton I mean any number *with 4 digits* the last of which is $5$.